# How to get the JIRA ticket number using Jenkins Declarative script

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jira

How to get the JIRA ticket number using Jenkins Pipeline script Example:

```
CICD-34
```

The following command gives complete info about the ticket, but how do we get just the ID and store in a variable?

**def issue = jiraJqlSearch jql: 'PROJECT = CICD AND description~"New JIRA Created from Jenkins through Declarative PL script"', site: 'MyLocalJira'”

echo issue.data.toString()**

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and find a solution.
I share with you my answer :)

```
def testExecutionSearch = jiraJqlSearch jql: "project=${project} and issuetype = 'Test Execution' and summary  ~ '${summary}'", site: 'myjira', failOnError: true

if (testExecutionSearch != null){
    //Get all issues
    def issues = testExecutionSearch.data.issues
    //Get the key of the first result
    def key = issues[0].key
}
```

Here I take the first element of my jql search (**def key = issues[0].key**) but you can choose what you want :)